# no puedo traer datos de API

Tags: fetch

Hola quisiera me pudieran ayudar, ya que no puedo traer datos de una API

```js
<script>
fetch("http://farmanet.minsal.cl/index.php/ws/getLocalesTurnos/",
 { method: "GET",
   headers: new Headers({ 'Content-type': 'application/json'}),
   mode: "no-cors",
   cache: "default"
})
.then(function(response) {
  return response.json()
})
  .then(function (turno) {
    document.getElementById("fecha").innerHTML = turno.fecha.valor;
    document.getElementById("fk_comuna").innerHTML = turno.fk_comuna.valor;
    document.getElementById("local_nombre").innerHTML = turno.local_nombre.valor;
    document.getElementById("comuna_nombre").innerHTML = turno.comuna_nombre.valor;
    document.getElementById("localidad_nombre").innerHTML = turno.localidad_nombre.valor;
    document.getElementById("local_direccion").innerHTML = turno.local_direccion.valor;
    document.getElementById("local_telefono").innerHTML = turno.local_telefono.valor;
    document.getElementById("funcionamiento_dia").innerHTML = turno.funcionamiento_dia.valor;
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log("Requestfailed", error);
  });
</script>
```

Hola quisiera me pudieran ayudar no he podido conseguir traer datos desde la esta API

Comment: ¿Qué aparece en la consola del navegador?

Comment: eso me sale en la consola: Requestfailed TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'fecha')

Comment: Analiza el JSON que devuelve la API ([lo puedes copiar/pegar aquí](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/#)). En primer lugar, **hay un array de objetos**, significa que debes leerlos **en un bucle o indicar el índice del objeto que quieres**; en segundo lugar, cada uno de esos objetos tiene **propiedades** como `fecha`, `fk_comuna` etc. así que no tiene sentido que pongas `.valor` cada vez, sino simplemente **el nombre de cada propiedad**, por ejemplo `elObjeto.laPropiedad`, así, si quieres la fecha: `elObjeto.fecha`.

Comment: Si por hacer una prueba lo pones así: `document.getElementById("fecha").innerHTML = turno[0].fecha;` deberías ver en el elemento la fecha del primer objeto. Pero esto no es lo ideal. Si esperas muchos objetos debes abrir un bucle y si esperas uno solo, deberías pedir ese sólo objeto a la API, o el código se recargaría innecesariamente y si es una API a cuotas, estarías consumiendo cuota de forma inncesaria.

Comment: al cambiar por turno[0].fecha; sigue marcando el error, sin embargo al analizar JSON en la url que diste, si pruebo la url dice que existe un problema, al copiar los datos directo me dice que esta ok, según documentación esta API no requiere ninguna KEY de uso.

Comment: En mi caso, probándolo localmente, si copiaba ese JSON devuelto en un archivo local y lo llamaba con el Fetch, funcionaba bien la carga del json (quitando todas las opciones del fetch).  Pero si lo intento con la URL que has puesto me sale el error de CORS por un lado u otro, haga lo que haga, por lo tanto entiendo que por ahí van los tiros.

Comment: Si en un `console.log(turno);` no ves la respuesta de la API, aunque sea en forma de texto, porque esa API por lo que sea no renderiza un JSON, entonces puede que haya un problema de CORS, como te indica @masterguru, en cuyo caso debes contactar con el SAT de la API para que te proporcione el modo de consultarla, si necesitas una KEY o algo. Y, si ves los datos, revisa las cabeceras, porque si es `text` o `html` vas a tener que hacer un parseo quizá.

Comment: para el CORS saque el error agregando cabeceras 
method: "GET",
headers: new Headers({ 'Content-type': 'application/json'}),
mode: "no-cors",
cache: "default"

Comment: Pon `console.log(turno);` y dinos si ves los datos en la consola. Y dinos si hay otros errores.

Comment: console.log(turno) sale el error pero no devuelve nada

Comment: He probado localmente y es extraño: por `fetch` puede ver los datos en la consola, pero dentro de recursos, y ahí dentro del apartado `getLocalesTurnos`, y los datos como texto, esa API está devolviendo contenido del tipo `text/html`, si intento con Ajax en cambio me da problemas de CORS.

Comment: Y si intento con cURL (entorno de servidor) me trae los datos, pero en forma de texto. Cabe decir que las restricciones CORS pueden estar también del lado de tu servidor, en mi caso tengo restricciones y autoricé temporalmente a esa URL, pues de lo contrario mis restricciones bloquarán también solicitudes a recursos externos.

Comment: Como quiera, si intento convertir la respuesta de cURL a un JSON no funciona, porque lo que parece estar ocurriendo es que la respuesta de la API contiene caracteres (en la respuesta misma) que invalidan el JSON. Cuando uno lo copia y pega desde el navegador el JSON valida en efecto en un validador en línea, pero a nivel de código no, puede que se esté colando algún BOM o algo en la respuesta que la hace inválida como JSON. No tendrás otra que contactar con la API.

Comment: realizare las consultas gracias